# ¿Como quitarle el espacio que genera el autozise a los textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente tengo un textarea al cual le implementé un autosize() con el motivo de que al escribir en este se expandiera cuando el texto haya completado todo el ancho del textarea, el autosize() si funciona el problema está que genera un salto de línea extra por así decirlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar en el cuadro rojo es lo que genera el autosize() al escribir el texto que se encuentra arriba

```js
$('#txt').autosize();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese espacio genera por tu `autosize()`

Prueba con este jQuery:

```
  $('.txt').autogrow({vertical: true, horizontal: false});
```

Más detalles de `autogrow()` [está aquí](https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow).